# Facing issue in onSelectionChange trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My main task is to use onSelectionChange() trigger; when the user selects some range of cells, I need to get the cell range in real-time and display the results in HTML div. Below is the google script code -:

```
// Function to send the selected range to an HTML div
function sendSelectionToHTML(selectedRangeA1) {
  // var range = getActiveRange();
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<div>' + selectedRangeA1 + '</div>');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

// Trigger the sendSelectionToHTML function when the selection is changed
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  // var range = e.range;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var selectedRangeA1 = range.getA1Notation();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1).setValue(selectedRangeA1);
  console.log(selectedRangeA1);
  sendSelectionToHTML(selectedRangeA1);
}
```

In the above code onChangeSelection() `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1).setValue(selectedRangeA1);` it updates the cell value as per required output, but when I call `sendSelectionToHTML(selectedRangeA1);` function inside onChangeSelection() it is not calling that function. Can someone guide me on where I am doing wrong? Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  var a1not = range.getA1Notation();
  sh.getRange(1,1).setValue(a1not);
  sendSelectionToHTML(a1not);
}
```